# How to create hooks in c# using delegates

Tags: c#, events, delegates

So this might be something really easy but I wanted to see if the concept of delegate would be appropriate.

I have the following method say on my main

```
PrintName();
GetId()
```

If I wanted to add "GetPhone()" Inject it if you will on my main, do I use delegate to this ?

My thought is the compiler will call main and only recognize methods on there, and has no idea if GetPhone() exist (since I just added it somewhere in the folder), the reasoning for this kind of architecture, is that I wanted to be able to just create a plug and play concept.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to manipulate a compiled binary, you won't get around looking into the MSIL Code and modifiying that. Start with ILSpy and some IL tutorials, then you'll see how to inject calls to functions yourself.

Comment: It's possible to load new assemblies dynamically (`Assembly.LoadFile`). Typically if you want a plug & play, you would write a bunch of interfaces that the plugins code against. Then in your application, you add code looking in a particular directory, and load all assemblies. Then you grab types defined against your interface, and execute them as normal

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt It doesn't at all look to me like they want to modify binaries, but to create plugin functionality

Comment: Rightright, I just read "hooks" and "compiler" and thought about reverseengineering and binary modifications, my fault.

Comment: thanks all, so @rob, can I use a list and loop thru the new added method in the interface ? theoretically the main can look thru the list and see if there are new added methods in the interface.

Comment: @PinoyDev Pretty much, yes. Something like: `foreach(var plugin in plugins.OfType<ICanGetPhone>()) { plugin.GetPhone(); }`

Comment: great! I'm excited to try it. Thank you all for the inputs

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Instead of calling the functions directly, you can use a delegate and then call the delegate, like this:

```
delegate void GetThings();
public GetThings myDelegate;
```

Then, you may assign or add functions to the delegate from your "plug and play" object.

```
myDelegate = PrintName();
myDelegate += GetId();
myDelegate = GetPhone();
```

As long as the return type is the same, you can add functions to the delegate (i.e. calling the delegate once you can call more than one function).
You will need to implement checks for security, though.